# How to calculate the volume of HNO3 needed to produce a specific concentration?

Tags: solutions, concentration

> How much $\pu{cm^3}$ of $\ce{HNO3}$, $\omega_{\ce{(HNO3)}} = \pu{63}\%$ with density $\ce{HNO3}$ of $\pu{1.4 g cm-3}$ do we need to create $\pu{500 cm^3}$ of solution whose $c = \pu{0.2 mol dm-3}$?

I tried to solve it and got following answer:

\begin{align}
V_\ce{(HNO3)} &= ? \\
ω_\ce{(HNO3)} &= 63\% \\
\rho_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \pu{1.4 g cm-3} \\
V_\mathrm{(solution)} &= \pu{500 cm3} \\
c &= \pu{0.2 mol dm-3} \\
c &= \frac{n_\ce{(HNO3)}}{V_\mathrm{(solution)}}  \\
n_\ce{(HNO3)} &= c \times V_\mathrm{(solution)} \\
n_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \pu{0.2 mol dm-3} \times \pu{0.5dm^3}\\
n_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \pu{0.1 mol}\\
m_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \pu{6.3 g}\\
m_\mathrm{(solution)} &= \frac{m_\ce{(HNO3)} \times 100\%}{\omega_\ce{(HNO3)}}\\
m_\mathrm{(solution)} &= \frac{\pu{6.3 g} \times 100\%}{63\%}\\
m_\mathrm{(solution)} &= \pu{10 g}\\
\rho_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \frac{m_\ce{(HNO3)}}{V_\ce{(HNO3)}}\\
V_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \frac{m_\ce{(HNO3)}}{\rho_\ce{(HNO3)}}\\
V_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \frac{\pu{6.3 g}}{\pu{1.4 g cm-3}}\\
V_\ce{(HNO3)} &= \pu{4.5 cm^3}
\end{align}

Calculating mass of solution here wasn't needed. Also, my friends did the same exercise and they got answer: $\pu{7.14 cm^3}$

This is new lesson that we are taking and I quite don't understand it. Our teacher wrote these as formulas:

\begin{align}
\omega_\mathrm{solute} &= \frac{m_\mathrm{solute}}{m_\mathrm{solution}}\\
m_\mathrm{solution} &= m_\mathrm{solute} + m_\mathrm{solvent}\\
\rho &= \frac{m_\mathrm{solution}}{V}\\
c_\mathrm{supstance} &= \frac{n_\mathrm{supstance}}{V_\mathrm{solution}}
\end{align}

Are these formulas correct? If I made mistake, please point it out. I don't understand this part at all.

Comment: since ρ = Msolution / v ,
it should be 10g and not 6.3 divided by 1.4 in your last step
Hope this helps!

Comment: That's the thing. Teacher did another exercise as I did it up there (kinda similar, not same) and that's why I can't understand this whole thing. Once, she used formula that I wrote down in formulas section, second time she used formula from up there...

Comment: What was the other formula taught?

Comment: Formula written in first lesson was p = m(solution) / v (V of what????)
The other formula is same as mine
p = m(HNO3) / V (according to thins V should be used of solution, but in other case she used V of solute)
That's what makes me not understand this. I'll translate other exercises and edit my post in 10 minutes

Comment: Here is a picture of notepad in which I wrote it. I copy pasted what she wrote and translated question: https://imgur.com/a/fLy0lU4
W = concentration in percentage
R = density

Comment: What's $\omega$?

Comment: What's supstance?

Comment: Supstance in this situation would be HNO3. Omega is percentage of solute in solution (if in 100g of solution there is 50g of HNO3 that means that HNO3 is 50% of that solution)

Comment: @Zenix When you edit questions like these, please make sure to also remove the deprecated homework tag and give them a proper title.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン ♦Actually am newbie. Will remember in future...

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I think that you did so many individual calculations that you lost track of what you were doing. Obviously the amount (moles or grams) of concentrated acid used equals the amount of acid in the dilute solution. Let's use the subscript $\mathrm{i}$ for the initial concentrated solution and the subscript $\mathrm{f}$ for the subscript for the final solution.

$$c_\mathrm{i}\times V_\mathrm{i} = c_\mathrm{f}\times  V_\mathrm{f}\tag{1}$$

Rearranging

$$V_\mathrm{i} = \frac{c_\mathrm{f}\times  V_\mathrm{f}}{c_\mathrm{i}}\tag{2}$$

Now $V_\mathrm{f}$ has units of $\pu{cm^3}$, which is fine for a volume measurement. But $c_\mathrm{f}$ has units of $\pu{mol \cdot dm^3}$ but the concentrated acid is given as $63\%$ by weight. So we need to convert the concentration acid to $\pu{mol \cdot dm^3}$ so that the units cancel.

$$c_\mathrm{i} = \frac{0.63 \times \pu{1.4 g/cm^3} \times \pu{1000 cm^3/dm^3}}{\pu{63 g/mol}} = \pu{14.0 mol/dm^3}\tag{3}$$

Now going back to equation 2

$$V_\mathrm{i} 
= \frac{c_\mathrm{f}\times V_\mathrm{f}}{c_\mathrm{i}} 
= \frac{\pu{0.2 mol/dm^3}\times \pu{500 cm^3}}{\pu{14.0 mol/dm^3}} 
= \pu{7.1 cm^3}\tag{4}$$

Comment: Thank you, I mostly understand what are you saying. I know I did a lot of calculations but that's how we are encouraged to work. We actually never learned this approach (using initial and final variables). Thank you again for introducing me to this new approach and I'll definitely research it and try to understand it a bit more.